# Passing line to cut and assigning to variable (Bash)

Tags: bash, shell, stdin, cut

I am able to read in and print every first name like so:

```
while read input;
do
    echo $input | cut -d ',' -f 1
done
```

but if I try and assign it to a variable and print it does not work. it just outputs three blank lines. (there are only three records in my file). I tried other methods as well but I attached my most recent attempt.

```
while read input;
do
    firstName=$input | cut -d ',' -f 1
    echo $firstName
done
```

This is what my user list looks like:

```
Jet,Black
Faye,Valentine
Radical,Edward
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure it out. I had tried this solution before but forgot the echo in front of $input.

```
while read input;
do
    firstName=$(echo $input | cut -d ',' -f 1)
    echo $firstName
done
```

Comment: I think your whole `while` loop can be replaced by just `cut -d ',' -f 1` , omitting everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in a sub-shell.

You should be able to do something like:

firstName=$(echo $input | cut -d "," -f 1)

Comment: Yup that's what I did! I just posted it below